# SQL SERVER FOR XML PATH - Exporting data to excel using Integration Services

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis, for-xml-path

Using the help of SO and code below:

```
select t1.*,
       stuff( (select '; ' + coalesce(data1, '') + ',' + coalesce(data2, '')
               from table2 t2
               where t2.FK_TBL1_ID = t1.id
               for xml path ('')
              ), 1, 2, ''
            ) as Data1Data2
from table1 t1;
```

I successfully combined multiple rows with multiple columns into one row-one column in my sql view.

What i would ultimately like to achieve is to be able for each row with multiple columns combined, to break the line for the new record(row) when viewed inside an excel cell like below:

```
**Data1Data2Cell**

  aaaa, bbbb; 
  cccc, dddd;
    ....
```

Same functionality can be achieved in Excel using ALT+ENTER on each cell.

I tried using Char(10) and Char(13) to no avail.

Comment: You should also show us your current output, and then then tell us what is wrong with it.

Comment: `Data1Data2Cell aaaa,bbbb; cccc, dddd;` records on same line, not on a new one each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your first line of STUFF to this

```
 stuff( (select CHAR(10)+ coalesce(data1, '') + ',' + coalesce(data2, '')+'; '
```

This will introduce the necessary line break in the string correctly.

See <kbd>**[working demo here](http://rextester.com/OUYOF42846)**</kbd>

Please note that when you run this query in SSMS, you may not see the results correctly as typically results show up in grid view like below

[image: normal view]

To get the right view you should change your query results to text view by either pressing <kbd>cntrl</kbd>+ <kbd>t</kbd> or by clicking Query options from top menu(see screenshot below)

[image: results to text]

Finally after this your query will give you correct view of results like below

[image: text results view]

Comment: Thanks Joshi! My problem with the above code (and my initial code from what it seems) is that from db row i am trying to fit in one cell a "description of duties" and when someone enters many duties and presses enter to space them then with the above query i get `aaaa; bbbb, bb <new line> cc <new line> dd; in excel which is not correct. How do i escape 'enter' keeping it on same line and also avoid '&#X0D' display on my results?

Comment: I think i solved it by changing code to `... coalesce(REPLACE(REPLACE([Data2], CHAR(13),' '), CHAR(10),' '), '') ...`.